# Creating a sortable table in the backend?

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a custom view where informations are shown in table format. In the backend i want to create a view like this:

[image]

Do you know a module to achive this? Or how would you create  a module for that? 
Any hints are greatly welcome!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *view* you mean that you want to create a custom module page for administrators, check out [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) modules, especially tabledrag_example and tablesort_example.

However, if you want to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), check out [DraggableViews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module.